sm-s134d ( Galaxy A03) FRP Locked! Help!
I have a Galaxy A03, that was given to me a while back. I've had it sitting for a while. I am going to be as short as i can about this. It has aa FRP lock on it and i have tried Droidkit, EaseUS, Wondershare Dr.Phone, and Passfab!.. None of these worked ( Yes i paid for them). I was able to get into The back door and do a complete reset and wipe everything, including the Cache., I was able to get into Download mode and flash it as well, But it will not go past the FRP lock. I did try with the SAMFw  tool,and while i was able to flash it with that , and i did it once with odin, it still does not get past the FRP lock!
One other thing the #0# code does nothing. I am able to use the ##88##, and it takes me to the MIE or MEI screen or something.
Any ideas Since Flashing it wont even work?
Randy
